# How to a use the .size function on a pandas Dataframe while still keeping all columns in the group

Tags: python, pandas

I hope everyone is having a great Monday!

```
group = airBnb.groupby(['ids', 'names']).size().nlargest(10)
plt.pie(group, group['host_names'])
```

Above is the code I'm asking about. As you can see, I'm using the 'groupby' function and '.size' function to obtain the count of top 10 most frequently occurring names. I want to create a pie chart using the size as the information but I want to use 'names' to label each slice of the pie chart. When I try to reference names as I have done above, I get the error 'KeyError: 'names''. Can anyone help me with this issue?

```
id         name                 
48005494   Zeus                          1215
107434423  Blueground                    1172
359036978  Kia                            593
8534462    Barsala                        582
30283594   Global Luxury Suites           332
359066913  PCHSoCal                       308
194953121  Christian                      285
2154262    Condominium Rentals Hawaii     284
229095817  Loftium                        274
```

The output of print would suggest that the names are contained in the frame but I can't access them

Comment: `airBnb.groupby(['ids', 'names'], as_index=False).size().nlargest(10)`

Comment: airBnb = pd.read_csv(r'us-Hotel.csv')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the object `group` is a `series` and not a  `dataframe`. I tried a sample dataset here for your reference.

Try:
`airBnb.groupby(['ids', 'names']).size().nlargest(10).reset_index()`

Above converts it into a dataframe. I have tried the solution on a sample dataset here.

Sample Input:

```
   ID NAME
0   1  ABC
1   1  ABC
2   1  ABC
3   1  ABC
4   2  XYZ
5   2  XYZ
6   3  KLM
7   4  NOP
```

Code:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['ID', 'NAME']).size().nlargest(10).reset_index()
df1 = df1.rename(columns={0 : 'Count'})
```

Output:

```
   ID NAME  Count
0   1  ABC      4
1   2  XYZ      2
2   3  KLM      1
3   4  NOP      1
```

Plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.pie(df1['Count'],labels=df1['NAME'])
```

Output:

[image: Plot]

Comment: This was exactly what I was after! Cheers for the help and effort, I understand my mistake now!

Comment: Glad that I could help!